# Wordpress - how to use post or page name as subdomain?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to use post name as subdomain.

For example I need to change:
example.com/test-page/ -> test-page.example.com
example.com/mypost/ -> mypost.example.com

Comment: I haven't used this plugin personally, but it may work for your purposes: https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-subdomains/

Comment: No this plugin do not work!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you can try using redirects with .htaccess (Apache) or .conf (nginx) to redirect URLs (automatic URL forwarding) to the subdomain.

In nginx:

```
location = / {
    # don't redirect http://example.com/
}

location / {
    # redirect everything else
    rewrite ^\/([^\/]*).*$ http://$1.example.com/ redirect;
}
```

Replace `redirect` with `permanent` depending if you want a temporary (HTTP 302) or a permanent (HTTP 301) redirect.

The empty `location = /` block is necessary so that you don't redirect http://example.com/ to http://.example.com/.